# Starting the debugger failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
// to generate numbers
void gen_data(int b[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i] = rand() % 101;
}
// to display numbers
void disp_data(int b[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d \n", b[i]);
}
// insert at desired posn
void insert(int b[], int n, int elt, int pos)
{
    int i;
    for (i = n - 1; i >= pos; i--)
        b[i + 1] = b[i];
    b[pos] = elt;
}
// delete an elt at given position
void delete (int b[], int n, int pos)
{
    int i;
    for (i = pos + 1; i < n; i++)
        b[i - 1] = b[i];
}
// driver code
int main()
{
    int a[100], pos, n = 10, let;
    int opt;
    system("cls");
    gen_data(a, n);
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n 1- Insert 2-Delete 3-Display 4-quit\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &pos, &elt);
        insert(a, n, elt, pos);
        n++;
        break;
        case 2:
            printf("enter position at which elt to be deleted: ");
            scanf("%d", &pos);
            delete (a, n, pos);
            n--;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("the numbers are : \n");
            disp_data(a, n);
            break;
    }
    if (opt == 4)
        break;
} // end while
}
```

Log:

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Users\Ranju\Desktop\you\lab pro\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\Ranju\Desktop\you\lab pro\
Adding file: C:\Users\Ranju\Desktop\you\lab pro\bin\Debug\lab pro.exe
Changing directory to: "C:/Users/Ranju/Desktop/you/lab pro/."
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C;C:\Users\Ranju\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args "C:/Users/Ranju/Desktop/you/lab pro/bin/Debug/lab pro.exe"
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: There is no `switch() {` for the `case 2:` and `case 3:` in main, also the comment `// end while` is not true, it is the `}` before.

Comment: Does it work if the path and application don't have spaces in them?

Comment: yes  I forgot to add switch here but I added it on code blocks and there were no error but the problem is I cannot debug

Answer (score 4):

In my case, removing space(s) from the project path resolved the problem. Maybe you should try to change path like this:
"C:/Users/Ranju/Desktop/you/**labpro**/bin/Debug/lab pro.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue when starting to use CodeBlocks on Windows10 (C::B version 20.03 in my case).  The problem was that I also had MinGW installed long before I installed CodeBlocks and CodeBlocks took the `gdb.exe` from that path instead of taking it from the MinGW path that was installed within CodeBlocks.
The solution for me was to change the default executable path in ***Settings -> Debugger... -> GDB/CDB debugger -> Default*** to the `gdb.exe` that was installed when I installed CodeBlocks. So: `<C::B_installation_path>\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`.

After that change, the problem was solved.

Comment: I tried this too and I'm at least getting a new error! On windows try entering ``where gdb.exe`` in the command line to see if you have multiples installed. I had one from MinGW and MYSYS for some reason. I switched to the MYSYS and get a new error so at least I'm making progress!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how relevant this may be, but I seem to have the same or similar problem. See the material at

[How do you debug using 'Code::Blocks 20.03' (the "mingw" version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045842/how-do-you-debug-using-codeblocks-20-03-the-mingw-version)

especially that after  the sentence, `I have hopefully made progress towards an answer.`.

---

I have now added a proper answer to the above question..

---

I asume that you have `MinGW` installed, in the directory `C:\MinGW`.

Perhaps, **AT YOUR OWN RISK**, you could try temporarily renaming the folder `C:\MinGW` to something else, and try running the debugger.

I had `MinGW` pre-installed, when I installed `Code::Blocks 20.03` using  `codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe` ( the 8th April 2021 version , default installation accepted). I also had a problem debugging. There is now a fix for this, which seems quite general, applying even without a pre-installed `MinGW`, see the answer to the other question ( link provided above ).

The fix involves changing a debugger setting, but in your case, you seem to be trying to use the correct debugger, see the line that you give, which is shown just below

`Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args "C:/Users/Ranju/Desktop/you/lab pro/bin/Debug/lab pro.exe"`

In the above, you appear to be trying to use a debugger,  from the directory,  `C:\Program Files\Codeblocks\MinGW\bin`, which seems O.K., rather than one from `C:\MinGW\bin`, which is where the debugger was, that I was trying to use, see the other question.

However, you may be using something other than the debugger from the directory `C:\MinGW`.

---

Whether or not you have `MinGW` installed in `C:\MinGW`, you may need to alter some `Setting` in `Code::Blocks`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  I am currently running Code::Blocks 17.12 on Windows 10.  In my case, I simply upgraded my compiler to Mingw64 bit. To fix: I changed an entry in the `default.conf` file located in `c:\users\logonname\appdata\roaming\codeblocks`
directory.  After making a copy of the original file I changed the line corresponding to the old debugger, `gdb32.exe` to the new file `gdb.exe` in its new directory.  That fixed the problem. This was the `default.conf` old line, before making my change: `<![CDATA[C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb32.exe]]>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug happen to me recently, when I began using codeblocks to learn C. I did four steps (isolated, none of them solved the problem):

1. I checked the paths and versions of both the debugger and the compiler to make sure they were correct;
2. Made sure that no other version of MinGW was installed on the PC (only keeping the one who is installed along with codeblocks);
3. Renamed the project so that the were no spaces;
4. Changed the directory of the project back into C:\Program Files (it was on a secondary hard disk).

It worked for me.

Comment: I cannot remove the spaces in the path because a cloud storage policy. Is there any other solution?

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to name files with whitespaces (for programming). Seems like a weird policy. Try renaming the project with CamelCase or using underscores.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. I know putting blank spaces is a bad practice, but I cannot remove such spaces because of the policy of the cloud storage service I use. I cannot change the folder's name. Thus, I am looking for an alternative solution.